# Add missing keys in Dataframe so that all dicts in Dataframe have same keys

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of dicts Where one dict may have more keys than other e.g.

```
[
  {
    "First Name": "qwert",
    "Last name": "fgh",
    "Status": "status",
    "18/02/22": "4.11",
    "20/02/22": "17.13"
  },
  {
    "First Name": "updated",
    "Last name": "fgh",
    "Status": "status",
    "19/02/22": "14.0",
    "22/02/22": "8.48"
  }
]
```

You see above dicts have Date as keys. FIrst, dict don't have 19/02/22 as well as 22/02/22 and the Second dict don't have 18/02/22 & 20/02/22 . Now Is there any way in pandas so That I can add missing keys with empty values so that all dicts have the same keys like

```
[
  {
    "First Name": "qwert",
    "Last name": "fgh",
    "Status": "status",
    "18/02/22": "4.11",
    "19/02/22": "",
    "20/02/22": "17.13",
    "22/02/22": ""
  },
  {
    "First Name": "updated",
    "Last name": "fgh",
    "Status": "status",
    "18/02/22": "",
    "19/02/22": "14.0",
    "20/02/22": "",
    "22/02/22": "8.48"
  }
]
```

Basically, I am converting this dict into excel file using Pandas and if all dict don't have sam ekeys then resultant excel don't have dates col in order. It looks something like
[image]

You see 19/02/22 comes after 20/02/22 since first dict don't have 19/02/22.

So it can be a large Dataset and basically, I want excel file have All Dates in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert to DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
  First Name Last name  Status 18/02/22 20/02/22 19/02/22 22/02/22
0      qwert       fgh  status     4.11    17.13      NaN      NaN
1    updated       fgh  status      NaN      NaN     14.0     8.48
```

And then sorting datetimes by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with key parameter and convert values to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
df = df.fillna('').sort_index(axis=1, key=f, na_position='first')
print (df)
  First Name Last name  Status 18/02/22 19/02/22 20/02/22 22/02/22
0      qwert       fgh  status     4.11             17.13         
1    updated       fgh  status              14.0              8.48


L = df1.to_dict(orient='records')
print (L)
[{'First Name': 'qwert',
  'Last name': 'fgh', 
  'Status': 'status', 
  '18/02/22': '4.11',
  '19/02/22': '',
  '20/02/22': '17.13', 
  '22/02/22': ''},
 {'First Name': 'updated', 
  'Last name': 'fgh',
  'Status': 'status', 
  '18/02/22': '', 
  '19/02/22': '14.0',
  '20/02/22': '', 
  '22/02/22': '8.48'}]
```